# How can I make wrapped text disappear without interfering with a floated DIV?

Tags: css

I have a header/title bar that isn't resizing the way I want it to. It contains a page title (which could be anything, of any length) and I don't want the text to wrap. So let's say I have a title bar for a page called "Approve a Room Request":

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <span id="name">Approve a Room Request</span>
  <span id="edit">Edit</span> 
  <span id="delete">Delete</span>
</div>
```

- Only "name" resizes with wrapper
- "Name" doesn't wrap to a second row (it has overflow: hidden)
- None of the spans should have a defined width
- Edit/Delete float right, Name floats left
- The spans don't have to be in that order in markup, but should *appear* that way on the page

Below: The first image is ideal. The second image shows that "edit" and "delete" don't have a fixed width. The third image shows that if the container is resized too small, "name"'s overflow gets thrown out (and doesn't wrap).

[image: example]

So far, the solutions I've come up with have bumped "edit" and "delete" to a second line, or made the "name" text disappear entirely when it was forced to wrap. Anyone know if this is possible to pull off? Thanks for reading!

Comment: For clarification: In the third example, you want "request" to wrap to a new line and 'disappear' without anything happening to its parent wrapper or sibling span-elements to the right?

Comment: The third example is the desired outcome - I know it's not pretty, but I really want this thing to have a predictable height. So "request" doesn't have to wrap anywhere. But yes, I want the wrapper and the siblings untouched.

Comment: Using `text-overflow: ellipsis` would be a nice addition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you’ll have to wrap the Edit/Delete/etc. controls in their own element, and absolutely position that:

- http://jsfiddle.net/5bYjK/

Alternatively, you can reverse the order of the title and controls, and float the controls:

- http://jsfiddle.net/5bYjK/3/

Either way, `white-space: nowrap` applied to `#name` seems to sort out the undesired wrapping.

I’ve only tested this in Chrome 16, but in theory, [`white-space: nowrap` is supported in most browsers](http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/white-space%3Anowrap).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I ended up going with the second solution. A lot simpler than I was making it.